# Sync Framework create duplicates from provisioned Client Database?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We have a large number of client databases with the same schema and does anyone knows how to create duplicates (like snapshot in SQL Server CE) from a provisioned client database, where the duplicates also can be synchronized with the server, since it takes really a long time to provision each client separately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup of an existing provisioned database, restore on client, run PerformPostRestoreFixup before you sync the restored database for the first time.

Comment: Is it possible to duplicate a provisioned & Synced database?(duplicate with data)

Comment: I have followed these steps. (1) Create Server DB and client DB (2) provision both DBs. (3) Insert data to Server (4) synchronize (5) duplicate client DB (6) run PerformPostRestoreFixup in duplicated DB (7) synchronize duplicated DB (want work ,but no errors)

Comment: can you clarify what didnt work? did you make some changes and the changes didn't sync? are you handling ApplyChangeFailed events?

Comment: this seems weird. (1) Provision server & Client A db (2) Sync server & Client A (3) duplicate Client A and Create Client B (4) run PerformPostRestoreFixup  on Client B (5) Insert records to Client B (6) Sync server and Client B (records successfully synced)  (7) Add records to Client A (8) Sync Client A with Server (added items not synced with Server). I have added an empty ApplyChangeFailed event. (not implemented the the body )

Comment: put some code on ApplyChangeFailed event so you know if it's firing some error/conflict. what are you using for your PK?